# Unzip and rename files keeping original file extension

Tags: r, unzip

I want to unzip the files inside a folder and rename them with the same name as their `.zip` file of origin BUT keeping the original extension of the individual files. Any ideas on how to do this?

Reproducible example:

```
# Download zip files
  ftppath1 <- "ftp://geoftp.ibge.gov.br/malhas_digitais/censo_2010/setores_censitarios/se/se_setores_censitarios.zip"
  ftppath2 <- "ftp://geoftp.ibge.gov.br/malhas_digitais/censo_2010/setores_censitarios/al/al_setores_censitarios.zip"
  download.file(ftppath1, "SE.zip", mode="wb") 
  download.file(ftppath2, "AL.zip", mode="wb")
```

What I had in mind was something as naive as this:

```
# unzip and rename files
  unzip("SE.zip", file_name= paste0("SE",.originalextension))
  unzip("AL.zip", file_name= paste0("AL",.originalextension))
```

In the end, these are the files I would have in my folder:

```
SE.zip
AL.zip

AL.shx
AL.shp
AL.prj
AL.dbf

SE.shx
SE.shp
SE.prj
SE.dbf
```

Comment: How do you want to treat folders? What happens if two files have the same extension?

Comment: Essentially what you need to do is take each zip file, save the name of the zip without the last 4 characters (which you can do with `substr`). Then open the zip, extract the name of the file, grab the extension with a regular expression (as there may be different extensions) and paste that extension at the end of the zip name you saved earlier. Then save the file under that name and expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for (stem in c('SE','AL')) {
    zf <- paste0(stem,'.zip'); ## derive zip file name
    unzip(zf); ## extract all compressed files
    files <- unzip(zf,list=T)$Name; ## get their orig names
    for (file in files) file.rename(file,paste0(stem,'.',sub('.*\\.','',file))); ## rename
};
system('ls;');
## AL.dbf  AL.prj  AL.shp  AL.shx  AL.zip  SE.dbf  SE.prj  SE.shp  SE.shx  SE.zip
```

Comment: This works on the example file names provided, but can't necessarily be generalized safely. If a subsequent zip file, say ZZ.zip, contained a file with the same name as one previously renamed, say AL.dbf, the original would be overwritten. Safer approach would be to adapt this answer to unzip into temporary folder, then rename and move.